# Sparql- Select query as input and transform it into "Construct "query.?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, endpoint

Im doing small task on Sparql and Jena. Basically I have to write a code that take any "select" query as input and Transform it into "Construct" Query.

It should be done through Java Code.

I have good understanding on "select" query and "construct" query. But this task confuses me. I'm doing simple sparql query only. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    // Select films and actors that appeared leonardo di caprio films // 

    "Prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"
                + "Prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"
                + "select ?film ?actor where {\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "?film a dbo:Film .\r\n" + 
                "?film dbo:starring ?actor.\r\n" + 
                "?film dbo:starring dbr:Leonardo_DiCaprio\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "}";

String service1 = "https://dbpedia.org/sparql"; // for select query 

Query query = QueryFactory.create(query1); 

        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service1,
                query);

         ResultSet results = qe.execSelect(); 




         while (results.hasNext()){
             QuerySolution s=results.nextSolution();
             System.out.println(s);  

         }
```

The output will display the results for select query but for this task, I want to write  java code that take any "Select" query as input and transform it into "Construct" query(Not result). The construct query should display in the output for example.

```
OUTPUT:

Construct {?actor <Mov:Starring> ?film.}
Where {
?film a dbo:Film . 
?film dbo:starring ?actor.
?film dbo:starring dbr:Leonardo_DiCaprio
}
```

Is there a way to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what means *transform* here? why can't you simply use the SELECT inside the CONSTRUCT? show an example please

Comment: @AKSW, I will put up the example soon.

Comment: @AKSW, The example query is shown above. Please have a look. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Just for clarification, you have a `SELECT` query and want to transform it into a CONSTRUCT query automatically via Java? Then copy the triple patterns of the `SELECT` query into the first and second part of the `CONSTRUCT` query

Comment: Maybe too simple, but for basic graph patterns:  Input: `SELECT ... WHERE {BGP}` Output: `CONSTRUCT {BGP} WHERE {BGP}` - or just put the whole `SELECT` query into the `WHERE` part.

Comment: if you want only triples produced by the projection variables of the `SELECT` query - which only works as long as you have exactly three variables, just use those in the first part of the `CONSTRUCT`

Comment: @AKSW, the output should show  "CONSTRUCT {BGP} WHERE {BGP}", I dont want to display the query results. I just want to know how can you use select query and transform it into construct query.

Comment: @AKSW, I will  put up  new example that includes jena code.

Comment: Well, I told you that you can "copy" the BGP from the SELECT query into the WHERE part of the CONSTRUCT query. What you can't solve automatically, is the conversion of the projection variables of the SELECT query into the first part of the CONSTRUCT query. I mean, in your example you reversed both variables and introduced a new property. Sure, if you're always doing the same, then it works - but for an arbitrary SELECT query, how should this be possible without a human looking at the SELECT query?

Comment: [`query.getQueryPattern`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Query.html#getQueryPattern--) returns the triple patterns of the WHERE part of the SELECT query. Just build the CONSTRUCT query with it